# Is there Ambari installation of HANA Spark Controller 1.5?

Tags: apache-spark, hana, vora

Currently I can only see the file HANASPARKCTRL00P_5-70001262.RPM in SAP SWDC under HANA Platform Components. Does it mean that Ambari-managed installation is no longer supported, or I simply miss the required authorisation in the Services Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Ambari installation for Spark Controller 1.5. It is only possible as of Spark Controller 1.6. The installation instructions can be found in the [HANA Admin Guide](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Administration_Guide_en.pdf) (current version is from 5/11/2016) -> chapter "9.2.3.1 Set up Spark Controller using Ambari" as well as in the attachments of [SAP Note 2318054 "SAP HANA Spark Controller 1.6.0 SPS 11 and Higher (Compatible with Spark 1.5.2)"](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2318054).